# What are the benefits of Extented-, Substract-, Inverts-, Intersect- existing selction icons im Viewport Editor

Tags: 3d-view

[image: What are the benefits of Extented-, Substract-, Inverts-, Intersect- existing selction icons im Viewport Editor].
Can you please explain, what practical use the symbols have.

Comment: "Selecting Modes" at the bottom of [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html?highlight=selection%20tool%20settings) page in the Blender manual should explain them. Hover over each icon to see the descriptive text and then read the description in the manual.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have read and understand the text in the manual, but I do not see the benefit or when do I use the individual selction. Sorry, but I've never needed, I don't get it. I do not have any clue.

Comment: I doubt many people do use them to be honest. I've been using Blender off and on for several years now and don't think I've ever needed to use any of them!

Answer (score -1):

have now understood what the icons are good for. So you don't always have to hold down the extra keys or the mouse button when selecting each mode. Had just not understood it because I had never tried the icons.

Thanks for your help